# Variadic template and copy constructors

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013

Why does the following not compile:

```
struct a
{
    int i;
};


template <typename T>
class b
{
public:
    T mItem;


    template <typename... Arguments>
    b(Arguments&&... args) : mItem(std::forward<Arguments>(args)...)
    {
    }
};


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    b<a>(1);

    return 0;
}
```

> error C2664: 'a::a(const a &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'int'
>   to 'const a &'

But simply adding an extra argument like this make it compile:

```
struct a
{
    int i;
};


template <typename T>
class b
{
public:
    T mItem;


    template <typename... Arguments>
    // just random extra argument
    b(int, Arguments&&... args) : mItem(std::forward<Arguments>(args)...)
    {
    }
};


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    b<a>(1);

    return 0;
}
```

Is there a cleaner way than simply adding an extra (useless) argument to b's constructor?

Comment: Because of value-initialization, aggregate-initialization and all that jazz.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to rely on aggregate-initialization, but you need to use braces rather than parentheses to use it:

```
template <typename... Arguments>
b(Arguments&&... args) : mItem{std::forward<Arguments>(args)...}
{
}
```

The braces mean that you are using list-initialization rather than value-/direct-initialization. The former resolves to aggregate-initialization when `T` is an aggregate type, but the latter two do not. Yeah, C++ initialization rules are weird.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case you try to invoke

```
a(1)
```

which you have not.

In the second case, your `1` parameter is consumed by `int` and the rest parameters (that is, none) goes to `args`. Therefore, you invoke

```
a()
```

which is ok.

Note that in the latter case, the value of `1` which you passed to `b<a>::b` is lost and is not forwarded to `a::i` as you might have expected.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to initialize A with int. A does not know anything about int, there is no constructor in A which can do this. When you provide an extra int argument, you are just discarding it and than initialze A with empty argument list, calling default constructor.

Comment: This answer obscures the extremely important effect of value-initialization.